# Confirm resubmission error on back button "Python with Django"

Tags: python, django

I built a web application where user can login and view work orders, property list and external contractors. However when I click back button on view property list page or view work orders page or view external contractors page it gives me an error saying confirm resubmission.
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQncr.png)

```
def user_login(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        user = authenticate(username=cd['username'], password=cd['password'])

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                if request.user.username == 'propertymanager':
                    #return HttpResponse('Authenticated successfully')
                    return render(request, 'account/dashboard.html', {'section': dashboard})
                elif request.user.username == 'technician1':
                    #return HttpResponse('Authenticated successfully')
                    return render(request, 'account/technician_dashboard.html', {'section': dashboard})
                elif request.user.username == 'technician2':
                    return render(request, 'account/technician2_dashboard.html',{'section': technician2_dashboard})
                else:
                    return render(request, 'registration/incorrect_user.html', {'section':incorrect_user})
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Disabled account')
        else:
            return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'section': incorrect_login})
    else:
        return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'section': incorrect_login})
else:
    form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form})
```

I tried replacing the last else with dashboard page

```
                else:
                return HttpResponse('Disabled account')
        else:
            return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'section': incorrect_login})
    else:
        return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'section': incorrect_login})
else:
    return render(request, 'account/dashboard.html', {'section': dashboard})
```

But now my login button doesn't work.
**Need Help! When I am on view property list page and click back button I should be able to see the dashboard**

Answer (score 0):

Each list should be its own view, not just its own template.

Please read the [django docs tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/) and follow the general guidelines presented there.

Comment: Can you please refer to which line of the code should be changed and to what !

Comment: Each view should only render one template, so after authenticating a user you should then redirect them to their page, which should be a new view which renders the template.

Comment: You can read up on djangos `redirect` helper, `login_required` and `user_passes_test` decorators

Comment: But I have multiple users who should login from the same Login page put each user after they login will have different HTML web pages. So I should have only one view to operate this!